# How to convert UTF-16 to ASCII/ANSI with XML/SGML entities?

Tags: xml, delphi, unicode, delphi-7

XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<center>
<b>Need to decode this -> </b>
</center>
</response>
```

My current code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  S: AnsiString;
  SW: WideString;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  Doc.LoadFromFile('example.xml');
  SW := Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['center'].ChildNodes['b'].NodeValue;
  S := '';
  for I := 1 to Length(SW) do
    if Ord(SW[I]) > $04FF then
      S := S + IntToHex(Ord(SW[I]), 4) + ' '
    else
      S := S + SW[I];
  Memo1.Text := s;
end;
```

`SW` is encoded in UTF-16 (Widestring) and contains the character sequence `#$D83D#$DE09`, but I need it as an XML/SGML entity like `'&#128521;'`. How do I encode this?

The character used is this: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f609/index.htm

Comment: Not really clear. So basically, you are dissatisfied what XML DOM implementation decoded a character outside basic multilingual plane and encoded it as two UTF-16 units? And want encode it back as SGML character entity?

Comment: don't really understood, i forgot to add XML Document... i will add it now

Comment: Against my better judgment, I tried to download your XML file. All I got were ads for NFL jerseys and download services. Can you not just paste the XML here in your question? If it's too big to post, then it's too big to bother reading anyway, so cut it down to the minimum that demonstrates your problem, and then paste it here.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here. What's wrong with the UTF-8 XML that you show? I can't see anything that needs to be decoded?

Comment: The problem I have described.

Comment: I think I understand your problem, you want to transcode UTF-16 (The WideString which is loaded from the XML file) to 7-Bit ASCII with everything > 7-Bit encoded as SGML/XML entity.

Answer (score 0):

When using ANSI Delphi you have to deal with UTF-16 surrogate pairs manually (or use some third party library).

This should work in ANSI und Unicode Delphi:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  Xml.XMLDoc, Xml.XMLIntf, System.AnsiStrings, System.Character;
  {$ELSE}
  XMLDoc, XMLIntf;
  {$ENDIF}

{$R *.dfm}

type
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
    ValueString = UnicodeString;
{$ELSE}
    ValueString = WideString;
{$ENDIF}

procedure Check(ATrue: Boolean; const AMessage: string);
begin
  if not ATrue then
    raise Exception.Create(AMessage);
end;

function IsHighSurrogate(AChar: WideChar): Boolean;
begin
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  Result := TCharacter.IsHighSurrogate(AChar);
{$ELSE}
  Result := (AChar >= #$D800) and (AChar <= #$DBFF);
{$ENDIF}
end;

function ConvertToUtf32(AHigh, ALow: WideChar): Integer;
begin
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  Result := Ord(TCharacter.ConvertToUtf32(AHigh, ALow));
  {$ELSE}
  Check(AHigh >= #$D800, 'Invalid high surrogate code point');
  Check(AHigh <= #$DBFF, 'Invalid high surrogate code point');
  Check(ALow  >= #$DC00, 'Invalid low surrogate code point');
  Check(ALow  <= #$DFFF, 'Invalid low surrogate code point');
  // This will return the ordinal value of the Unicode character represented by the two surrogate code points
  Result := $010000 + ((Ord(AHigh) - $D800) shl 10) or (Ord(ALow) - $DC00);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

function MakeEntity(AValue: Integer): AnsiString;
begin
  Result := Format(AnsiString('&#%d;'), [AValue]);
end;

function UnicodeToAsciiWithEntities(const AInput: ValueString): AnsiString;
var
  C: WideChar;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  I := 1;
  while I <= Length(AInput) do
  begin
    C := AInput[I];
    if C < #$0080 then
      Result := Result + AnsiChar(C)
    else
    if IsHighSurrogate(C) then
    begin
      Check((I + 1) <= Length(AInput), 'String truncated after high surrogate');
      Result := Result + MakeEntity(ConvertToUtf32(C, AInput[I + 1]));
      // Skip low surrogate
      Inc(I);
    end
    else
      Result := Result + MakeEntity(Ord(C));
    Inc(I);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := string(UnicodeToAsciiWithEntities(LoadXMLDocument(
    'example.xml').DocumentElement.ChildNodes['center'].ChildNodes['b'].NodeValue
  ));
end;
```

I don't have Delphi 7 here, so some minor adjust might be necessary, the code works in XE2 and 2007.

Comment: The XML document declares its encoding to be UTF-8

Comment: Rather than convert the entire XML content to `UCS4String` and waste 2-4x the memory, I would leave it as `UnicodeString` and just loop through it looking for surrogates and converting them to entities when needed. Look at `System.Character` functions like `IsSurrogatePair()` and `ConvertToUtf32()`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's true, but that doesn't matter since the XML parser converts this to the internal Delphi representation (WideString for Delphi 7) anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I refactored the code to work in ANSI and Unicode Delphi versions.